# Can't find Python executable "python"

Tags: python, node.js, npm, ubuntu-server

When i install `iconv` with `npm` got the following error:

> iconv@2.1.0 install /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeApp/node_modules/iconv
>   node-gyp rebuild

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:42:11
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:25)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeApp/node_modules/iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! iconv@2.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@2.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the iconv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls iconv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! cwd /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeApp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeApp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

although I installed python and can run it from console:

```
# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, May  9 2014, 12:18:32) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
```

and set up `PATH` in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Python-2.7.3
export PATH=$PATH:/Python-2.7.3
```

and done `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: the problem was because of `~/.bashrc` was not loaded on ssh login. I put `PATH` vars to `~/.bash_profile` and it's ok

Comment: I had the PYTHON var set in ~/.zshrc but kept getting the error after restarting iTerm, so I ended up with this symlink hack:
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 104):

For anyone encountering this issue on Ubuntu 16.04...
`node-gyp` can't use Python 3.5.X which seems to the be the default that ships with 16.04. I read somewhere that 16.04 was supposed to ship with Python2 as well but I can't find it on my install.

I fixed the above issue by:

```
apt-get update     
apt-get install python2.7    
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Now when `node-gyp` goes looking for `python` it will hit your Python2.7 install and load correctly.

Comment: You can't put `ln` in bashrc though. It requires sudo access. How do you do this permanently?

Comment: @towi_parallelism You can set the `PYTHON` environment variable. Do it like this: `export PYTHON="$(which python2.7)"`. It does seem rather silly that node-gyp is still locked to Python v2.7 when it's being retired in just 5 months......

Comment: I am giving an up vote to this answer. I am using ubuntu 20.04 in which python 2.7 was not installed. Main python version is 3.8. I am using angular cli 9. I was getting this error after npm install " import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];" and found out that there is syntax change in newer version of python. Based on that, I installed pyhon 2.7 and set npm config python path to 2.7. I worked after that

Answer (score 11):

In your bash session where you're able to just type `python` and get a valid response, type in `which python` and note the full path location of the `python` binary. Take that location and put that into your `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` environment variables, except without the `python` at the end.

For example, `which python` gives me:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

so I would write:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

in my `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: `-bash: :/usr/bin: No such file or directory`

Comment: make sure you are using sudo -s

Answer (score 11):

There is a simple and safe way
Place this into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias python=python3
```

After adding the above in the file, run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_aliases`

This solution worked for my Ubuntu
see the origin answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)

Answer (score 8):

Install python2.7.

`apt install python2`

Comment: In the question, it is explicitly stated that python2.7 is already installed and can be run from the shell using `python`.

Comment: I didn't have the problem that OP had, but I was seeing something similar, and this fix did the trick.  (In my case, I'm on Ubuntu and didn't have Python2 installed.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You can solve it like this:

```
sudo apt install python2
npm config set python "/usr/bin/python2.7"
```

But if you don't want to downgrade python3..

```
npm install -g node-gyp@latest
npm config set python "/usr/bin/python3.8"
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem was because of `~/.bashrc` was not loaded on ssh login. I put `PATH` vars to `~/.bash_profile` and it's ok

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is not only related to NPM. So, a system-wide solution is required. Then, just create a system-wide symlink for 'python' to your current python path.

For example, for my Ubuntu 20 setup (be root):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Then verify the symlink:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Feb 19 13:55 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: In addition to your answer, in my case, it was needed python2. I did `sudo apt install python2` and then as you said `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python`