# Error: Can't find Python executable "python"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

SO, I've set python path as in ~/.profile

```
export PYTHON=$PYTHON:/usr/bin/python
```

I'm getting.

```
stack Error: Can't find Python executable ":/usr/lib/python:/usr/lib/python3.5:/usr/lib/python3.5:/usr/bin/python3.5:/usr/bin/python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

What will be the path to the executable python ?

Comment: Why is there a colon in front?

Comment: @user2357112: Sounds like someone is confusing the `PATH` variable with general usage of file paths. The OP needs to clarify what they mean by "set python path as /usr/lib/python" (for one, why would the `python` executable be installed to `/usr/lib`, not `/usr/bin`?)

Comment: You mean `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/python` in `.bashrc` file?

Comment: I have updated question, please have a look and suggest

Comment: I answered speculatively, but I can't be 100% sure it's right since you didn't specify the tool you are using that treats `PYTHON` as a special environment variable. It's not a standard variable supported by the CPython reference interpreter or `bash` itself, it looks like some special tool is using it to find `python`, but that makes the question about that tool, not about Python or `bash` really.

Comment: I'd guess that it wants the `PYTHON` environment variable to be the path to the executable, not a `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`-like list of folders. Try `PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`, maybe. Like @ShadowRanger says, this is not really a Python question, it's more about the program that's giving you that message.

Answer (score 0):

Your tool seems to want the directory that might contain the executable named `python`, not the full path to the executable. Try changing it to: `export PYTHON=$PYTHON:/usr/bin`

Looks like your tool is likely `node-gyp` or some other `npm` related thing, in which case you might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23571257/364696) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15126050/364696) if the problem persists.