# NPM install can't execute Python in MAC

Tags: python, macos, npm

I'm new to MAC (OSX version is High Sierra 10.13.3). I installed python 3.6.5 with the installer from python.org and I tried doing it with brew too by running `brew install python`. Now, I'm trying to run `sudo npm install` in a Angular project and I get the following errors:

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/path/to/python3/python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /path/to/python3/python
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/python3/python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

I have tried all the answers in here :

[python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx)

[Can't find Python executable "python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571257/cant-find-python-executable-python)

Inside of my projects folder I do the following:

when I type 'which python' I get:

```
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
```

When I type 'which python3.6.5' I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

Comment: First, you've installed at least two extra Pythons on top of the one Apple preinstalled, instead of just one. That will just make things even more confusing. Uninstall one of them.

Comment: Second, have you actually put the literal string `/path/to/python3` or `/path/to/python3/python` somewhere? If so, you were supposed to substitute that with the actual path to python3, like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/` or `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`.

Comment: @abarnert Correct. I install the lastest version because I know MAC comes with a default one but when I was running npm install it has saying that I need python. With that being said, I see a executable in the launcer in the mac, but when I drag it to the trash can, it doesn't get uninstall. any safe way to do so?

Comment: First, you cannot uninstall the Python that came with macOS, and you do not want to. You can uninstall either of the two Python 3.6 versions, however. The simplest way is `brew unlink python`, which should remove the Homebrew one, leaving the python.org one.

Comment: @abarnert related to your second comment. I probably did. I have tried so many things for the past 3 hours. How can i reset the literal string? Also when i do brew doctor I notice this related to your first comment. Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6-config`

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're using `gyp`, AFAIK that's a dead project which doesn't support Python 3 and never will, which means installing Python 3.6 isn't going to help. Either use Apple's Python 2.7, or install another Python 2.7 instead. IIRC, for the former, it should be as simple as `npm install --python=python2.7`. But if you search for help on that, instead of help on Python installations that you didn't actually need to do, you'll probably find better information.

Comment: I have uninstall python from brew. I apologize for installing a python when I didnt need it. I'm new to macs. I did npm install --python=python2.7` and I got `gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2.7" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2.7` is there a way to set the PATH that way I can just do `npm install?`

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the `PATH`; if `python` runs the builtin Python 2.7 (as it did before you installed anything), it should just work. I believe `gyp` tries `python2` first, and Apple doesn't install anything with that name. That shouldn't be necessary, but if it is, you can make a symlink. Something like: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2`. But, again, it shouldn't be necessary in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert YOU are right in all these. I even ran that command and it was telling me that it already exist. I got the solution for my problem by deleting the repo and running npm install and it worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my node_modules folder was screwed up. I deleted the repo and cloned again and it worked.

Comment: npm -ci will delete the directory for you and install.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was all happening because of nodejs version.

Node version 16+ does not support "node-sass": "^4.14.1", so I have to install nvm and downgrade the nodesjs in macbook as follows

- Before installing nvm, run this in terminal: **touch ~/.bash_profile**
- After, run this in terminal: **curl -o-

  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh |
  bash**
- Important... - DO NOT forget to Restart your terminal OR use command
  **source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh** (this will refresh the available commands in
  your system path).
- In the terminal, use command **nvm --version** and you should see the
  version
- bash **nvm install 14.17.0**