# npm install doesn't work because of node-sass on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg, node-sass

I'm trying to `npm install` a project on Ubuntu but I'm getting this error:

```
Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
```

The solutions I found on Stack Overflow was to run `npm rebuild node-sass`, like in this thread:

[Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324519/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-linux-64-bit-with-false)

When I first tried this solution I got this error:

```
npm - “Can't find Python executable ”python“, you can set the PYTHON env variable.”
```

and the solution I found for it was to install Python 2.7, from here:

[Can't find Python executable "python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571257/cant-find-python-executable-python)

Now when I run python --version I get: Python 2.7.18

So I removed the node_modules folder and the lock file, and run `npm install` again, but it didn't work, and now I'm getting a build error, which you can find in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/aimad-majdou/b99c5295b56fd5bc68492fa638d63018

I never had issues installing this project on Mac OS and Windows, but this is the first time I try to install it on Ubuntu.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from the gist, that you're running node version 16.x on your ubuntu. As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67303155/907480), it is probably a version incompatibility between node 16 and the version of node-sass you're trying to build. You should be using at least version `6.0.1` of node-sass for node 16 support.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked that and I had to use node v14 instead of v16, now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions for this.

## 1. Fix python install for npm

You can tell npm to use the correct version of python by running the following command:

```
npm config set python python2.7
```

Hopefully after this you can build node-sass.

However, I personally use another solution:

## 2. Stop using node-sass

There is a pure-javascript **sass** implementation on npm called [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass). It is compatible with node-sass. Just replace `node-sass` with `sass`.

Of course, often you did not decide which sass module to use. Usually some framework like React decided to use binary modules like `node-sass` so you are forced to use it. Well, you can override it in your projcet.

Open your `package.json` file and edit the `node-sass` line in the `dependencies` to:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.30.0",
    ...
}
```

This tells `npm` to install [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) version 1.30.0 as **node-sass**. Since the sass from the sass module command is compatible with the sass command from node-sass you can now build your project without worrying about building sass. Of course you can use a more recent version of sass if you like.